# What does "struck" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs

When I was memorizing words in an APP, I found the following sentence.

> In Geneva, a historic deal is struck.

The app provides an explanation in another language that basically means the deal was blocked, it probably not happen soon. I looked up the work "strike" in dictionary, and found this explanation:

> [AmE informal] to not be successful at something

This seems fits the context well. But it's different from the app provided explanation. To corroborate, I put the original sentence in Google Translation and translate it to my native language. Surprisingly, the translation literally means "In Geneva, a historic deal was reached".

What does the original sentence really mean? Thanks.

Comment: I think the app was confused if it translated it as _blocked_. That would be a translation of _stuck_ not _struck_

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll remember their difference. Thanks for mentioning. The app is poorly built and I believe there are more errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: the phrase, "In Geneva, a historic deal is struck" means: *some people successfully make a very important agreement in Geneva*.

*Strike* is one of those seemingly simple verbs that actually has very many meanings, some of them quite different from others.

Look at this entry in the *Merriam-Webster* dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strike

There are 18 meanings for the verb when it's used intransitively (without a direct object, like in, "The two boats struck in the narrow channel") and another 24 meanings when it's used transitively (with a direct object, like in, "He struck me with his fist").

On top of that, we have idiomatic expressions like *strike out*, which comes from baseball (where it means to fail to hit a pitch three times, causing an "out" for your team).

One common expression with *strike* is [*to strike a deal*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strike%20a%20deal) which essentially just means *to make a deal*.

This expression is common enough that the words can be reordered and it will still sound natural: *they strike a deal*, *a deal was struck*, *striking a deal can be hard work*, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The "agreement was reached" is the correct meaning in this example. There are some cases where "struck" would mean blocked but this is not such a use.

For example, "The parties struck off negotiations" would have the meaning that negotiations ceased (for whatever reason).